# Picker color react on slide?

Tags: jquery-ui, wicket

I'm using color picker from this example:
 http://www.7thweb.net/wicket-jquery-ui/slider/ColorPickerPage?2

and I trying force Picker to change color on slide, no on onValueChanged (now it react when sliding end) but I'm fail.

anyone knows hot to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, it is a bad practice to send ajax request on mouse move. That's why 
AjaxSlider is not designed to handle the 'slide' event; it will send too much ajax requests...

Furthermore, Slider/AjaxSlider are designed to be FormComponent(s). For this to be possible, the Slider component embeds an hidden input and the 'slide' event is - then - used to update the input value as soon as the slider... slides. So you cannot use ColorPicker/AjaxSlider/Slider to achieve this.
You can still do your own (but I am afraid it wont be a FormComponent). If you need to get inspiration, you can have a look on ResizablePanel (& ResizableBehavior). This is one of the simplest component handling ajax requests...

Hope this helps.